# Metro bundler link 19000 shows json dump on react native expo instead of bundler web page with qr code

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I usually run expo start or expo start -c and a browser will auto open at localhost:19000 with the metro bundler details that displays the qr code, connection: tunnel, lan, local, and of course the exp: address of the app.

Suddenly, when I run expo start, the browser no longer open. and when I navigate to localhost:19000, it shows a json dump:

```
{"name":"litplans","slug":"litplans","version":"1.0.0","orientation":"portrait","icon":"./assets/icon.png","userInterfaceStyle":"light","splash":{"image":"./assets/splash.png","resizeMode":"contain","backgroundColor":"#ffffff","imageUrl":"http://127.0.0.1:19000/assets/./assets/splash.png"},"updates":{"fallbackToCacheTimeout":0},"assetBundlePatterns":["**/*"],"ios":{"supportsTablet":true,"bundleIdentifier":"com.mallsecinc.litplans"},"android":{"adaptiveIcon":{"foregroundImage":"./assets/adaptive-icon.png","backgroundColor":"#FFFFFF","foregroundImageUrl":"http://127.0.0.1:19000/assets/./assets/adaptive-icon.png"}},"web":{"favicon":"./assets/favicon.png"},"_internal":{"isDebug":false,"projectRoot":"C:\\sites\\apps\\litplans","dynamicConfigPath":null,"staticConfigPath":"C:\\sites\\apps\\litplans\\app.json","packageJsonPath":"C:\\sites\\apps\\litplans\\package.json"},"sdkVersion":"45.0.0","platforms":["ios","android","web"],"developer":{"tool":"expo-cli","projectRoot":"C:\\sites\\apps\\litplans"},"packagerOpts":{"scheme":null,"hostType":"lan","lanType":"ip","devClient":false,"dev":true,"minify":false,"urlRandomness":"2x-kif","https":false},"mainModuleName":"node_modules\\expo\\AppEntry","__flipperHack":"React Native packager is running","debuggerHost":"127.0.0.1:19000","logUrl":"http://127.0.0.1:19000/logs","hostUri":"127.0.0.1:19000","bundleUrl":"http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false","iconUrl":"http://127.0.0.1:19000/assets/./assets/icon.png"}
```

The only thing that I did different is uninstall and installing node.js.

To trouble shoot, I've done the following:

- Try to run an exisitng expo project.
- List item
- start a brand new expo project.
- remove node_modules and install again
- remove expo module and install again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Metro Bundler UI is no longer available after expo-cli@6.0.0

https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the issue. If you guys need to get to the tunnel just simply add the flag: expo start --tunnel

Answer (score -1):

For me using "start": "expo start" instead of "start": "expo start --dev-client" worked maybe if you share what your dependencies look like it would be helpful